# SELECT DISTINCT 2 columns and count the # of times it appears on either

Tags: mysql

I have an example table below:

```
user1 | status1 | user2 | status2
Maria      2      Ana        1
Elena      2      Angela     1
Angela     1      Ana        2
Maria      2      Elena      1
Elena      1      Ana        2
Maria      1      Akisha     2
Elena      1      Akisha     2
```

I want to count the number of times a name appears in either user1 or user2 where the value is 2 and also count the number of times it appears in either user1 ot user2 with a value of 1.

With the above example the desired result is:

```
user | statusis2 | statusis1
Akisha     2           0
Maria      2           1
Ana        2           1
Elena      1           3
Angela     0           2
```

As with the above, it is arranged by statusis2 DESC, statusis1 ASC

Thanks in advance for any help.

b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT user
     , SUM(status = 1) status1
     , SUM(status = 2) status2
FROM
(
SELECT user1 user, 1 status_type, status1 status FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT user2, 2, status2 FROM my_table
)x
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: tried this looks like it counts all appearances by a user on user1 as well as user2 regardless of status. for my example data above it gives akisha with 0 status2 (value is 2) and 2 status1 (value of 1)